# fixing the path so python can recognize z3 modules

Tags: python, linux, server, z3

I have successfully installed z3 on a remote server where I am not root. when I try to run my python code I get :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'z3'
```

I understand that I have to add it to PYTHONPATH in order to work and so I went ahead and done that like this:

> export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/usr/lib/python-2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH

I still get the same issue though, how can I verify that it was correctly added to the variables environment? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Btw I am using python3 to run my code, so maybe this also contributes somehow.

Comment: Check whether the directory you added to `PYTHONPATH` contains a folder called `z3`, which in turn contains a file called `z3.py`. At runtime, Python also needs to find `libz3.dll` (or `...so` or `...dyld` on Linux or OSX), which may need to be added your `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` depending on your system.

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger thank you for your answer, how can I get to PYTHONPATH? I am working on the univ server in which I am not root

Comment: Eeh... `cd $HOME/usr/lib/python-2.7/site-packages`?

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger  the setup is a bit different, this is a server where each of the users has a directory to work on, python was pre-installed by root. and so I have no python directory on my home directory(although I can use it as normal). that's the issue I can't solve

Comment: Then your `PYTHONPATH` is set up incorrectly; add the correct directory to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you pass the `--python` flag when you called `scripts/mk_make.py`?

See the instructions on https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/README.md on how to exactly enable Python (about all the way down in that page). Here's an example invocation:

```
python scripts/mk_make.py --prefix=/home/leo --python --pypkgdir=/home/leo/lib/python-2.7/site-packages
```

Change the directories appropriately, of course.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users that just downloaded and unzipped the compiled Z3 binary into some arbitrary directory, adding the location of the python directory in the directory where Z3 was installed to PYTHONPATH did the trick. ie in Cygwin : `$ export PYTHONPATH=<location of z3>/bin/python:$PYTHONPATH` (or the equivalent in a Windows command shell)